# com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView could not be found Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, google-play-services

I've been researching for days trying to figure this out. Anything to do with Google Play Services is colored red.
It's in the Gradle already the most up-to-date version
I've got all the pieces the websites says to put there and it's still red.

```
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.zanziv.rickandmorty.R;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import java.io.IOException;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



            AdView mAdView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());
```

dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'
```

xml

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="MINE"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: If you already have the SDK properly installed, try cleaning the project (Build -> Clean Project).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you add the SDK tools beforehand? 

Go on **SDK Manager** [image] **>** **Extras >** Select 
    **Google Repository** and
    **Google Play services** and install them.

For more details, read this [document.](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html)

Comment: Yes I did that before hand and I un/reinstalled prior to posting for help.

Comment: What does your logcat or event log report?

Comment: I could find it on "SDK Tools" instead of "Extras"

Answer (score 0):

In android studio Go to Preference(In Mac) - Editor - General - Auto Import

Check Add unambigious imports on the fly

Check the box as the picture shown [Auto Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17zNk.png)